# Version Control for developers new to source control

Tags: svn, version-control, backup

I've been writing code for a few years now and our backup strategy has been to zip the entire code directory up every few days and put it somewhere else on your hard drive, or occasionally upload it to some online file hosting service.

Unfortunately the file hosting service got canceled without telling me and we lost years of backups.  It's come down to the point where I finally have to learn to use version control.  The only problems are

1. My boss really doesn't like SVN, he tried it and it had a high learning curve (at least his client).
2. We need a reliable place to host it (we can pay a reasonable amount).

Can someone suggest what may be the best version control system and client for a newbie which won't be too annoying.

Second what is a good remote version control service?

Comment: I know this may have been better as as community wiki but I'm not sure of how to do that (I did check the FAQ, no luck).

Comment: only moderators can make questions CW now. They still change if 30 answers are posted or lots of edits are made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good user experience and good remote VCS:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/) ([git](http://git-scm.com/)): for learning that DVCS, see [Git Immersion](http://library.edgecase.com/git_immersion/index.html) (and [GitHub Help pages](http://help.github.com/)).
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) ([mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)): for learning that DVCS, see [HgInit](http://hginit.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If your boss thinks SVN is too steep a learning curve, chances are he'll need to be dragged kicking and screaming to use *any* modern version control system.  Maybe a GUI client
like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) would make things a bit more palatable?

And please remember that version control is no substitute for a sane backup policy!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jim, but what he hated was TortoiseSVN.  Heck, the IDE we use is like from 2003, so I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I really like SVN if you get a good client. I use "Versions" on the Mac and it's great. They even had/have a service called "beanstalk" which is hosted SVN. "Smart SVN" on Windows isn't half bad. "Tortoise" is nice if you're looking for file menu integration with Windows.

Second, the popular choice these days seems to be "Git".

Answer (score 1):

Compared to zipping files and copying them around, any source control system will have a learning curve.  That's because they provide real value.  Your boss will need to understand that he's investing something which will be repaid many times over.

All serious software developers (and many other types of creators) use source control as a way of managing and protecting their work.  It's a good thing, and worth it.

SVN is the simplest respected source control these days.  It's centralized, and distributed systems are much more popular, but it sounds like centralized would work well for you, and you wouldn't end up getting tangled in distributed concepts you don't need.

Comment: Well, we do have several developers in other countries.  Maybe decentralized would be better.